# Error in automated email generation in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

actually i'm doing a project using opencart(2.0.3.1)  the automated email notification facility for COD has stopped working but the data is inserting into the database(db) following the error I am getting

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: orderid in
> /home/glendalegreen/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl
> on line 34
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: name in
> /home/glendalegreen/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl
> on line 35
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: amt in
> /home/glendalegreen/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl
> on line 36
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: txndate in
> /home/glendalegreen/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl
> on line 37
>
> 2015-11-06 12:41:01 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: responsemsg in
> /home/glendalegreen/public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl
> on line 38

```
//confirm.php
//session_start();
$HASHING_METHOD = 'xxx';  // md5,sha1

// This confirm.php used to show payment status and response parameters.
if(!isset($_SESSION['SECRET_KEY']) || empty($_SESSION['SECRET_KEY']))
    $_SESSION['SECRET_KEY'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'; //set your secretkey here
    
$hashData = $_SESSION['SECRET_KEY'];
$response = array();
print_r($_POST, true);

//ksort($_POST);
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    if (strlen($value) > 0 && $key != 'SecureHash') {
        $hashData .= '|'.$value;
    }
}
if (strlen($hashData) > 0) {
    $secureHash = strtoupper(hash($HASHING_METHOD , $hashData));
    
    if($secureHash != $_POST['SecureHash']){
```

$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

```
$data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
    'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
    'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
);

$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
    'text' => $this->language->get('text_basket'),
    'href' => $this->url->link('checkout/cart')
);

$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
    'text' => $this->language->get('text_checkout'),
    'href' => $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL')
);

$data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
    'text' => $this->language->get('text_success'),
    'href' => $this->url->link('checkout/success')
);

$data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $data['text_message'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_customer'), 
    $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'),
    $this->url->link('account/order', '', 'SSL'),
    $this->url->link('account/download', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('information/contact'));
} else {
    $data['text_message'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_guest'), $this->url->link('information/contact'));
}


    } else {
        $response = $_SESSION['paymentResponse'][$_POST['PaymentID']];
    }
} else {
    echo '<h1>Error!</h1>';
    echo '<p>Invalid response</p>';
    exit;
}
    foreach( $response as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'paymentStatus') continue;
       //echo $key;
       //echo $value;
       
       $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE gl_xxxxx SET ".$key." = '".$value."' where MerchantRefNo='".$response[MerchantRefNo]."'");
       $this->cart->clear();
       
       

       $data['orderid'] = $response[MerchantRefNo];
       $data['name'] = $response[BillingName];
       $data['amt'] = $response[Amount];
       $data['txndate'] = $response[DateCreated];
       $data['paymentid'] = $response[PaymentID];
       $data['tranid'] = $response[TransactionID];
       $data['responsemsg'] = $response[ResponseMessage];
       $data['reqid'] = $response[RequestID];
       $data['hash'] = $response[SecureHash];
       $data['rescode'] = $response[ResponseCode];
       $data['paymethod'] = $response[PaymentMethod];
      }
```

Comment: The variables you are using in your mail template called success.tpl do not exist.

I cannot say more, because you are not providing any code. Please post your success.tpl source code and the part that is sending the mail.

Comment: yes finally understood how to send a mail add success full to my cart